# My terminal is flooded with errors?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

New user here, I've used Ubuntu for a few weeks now and I must have installed something incorrectly or something because any time I run `sudo apt update` I get a giant wall of errors. It probably comes from me installing drivers multiple times like a monkey. They look like this:

```
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Hit:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.4 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.1 kB]          
Ign:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease               
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:23 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                   
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1
```

I'm pretty sure the command works fine and updates everything not listed here, but I want to know how to get rid of all the errors. I don't think it's actually an issue, it's just an eyesore. The only thing I actually recognize is `E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.`, where "pcsx2" is my ps2 emulator that I use very often. If anyone could help me tidy up my terminal that would be wonderful!

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources; so all security checks are your responsibility, ie. is it trustworthy, good for your release etc..   A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2.official.ppa shows it doesn't support anything later than *bionic* or 18.04; so has nothing useful/safe for your *jammy* or 22.04 system - did you look ?

Comment: You've messed up your sources. Adding sources should not be taken lightly. In Linux, software frequently depends on other software to run properly. Software from the official/default sources/repos are designed to work with each other. When you add different sources, you change the library of available software and you may be adding software that call dependent versions of software that are different and incompatible with your current software. In particular, you should not add software from different releases. You have jammy, groovy, and hirsute and impish sources, and they are misconfigured.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know anything about sources, I just followed a few guides and got the games I wanted. Guess I didn't think my OS version was that important, either. "Messing up my sources" sounds bad, how can I mend this? Should I reinstall the proper versions or do I have to just reconfigure some things?

Comment: Remove the sources that didn't come with your system. Then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Once the system is up-to-date with the default sources, you should be able to release upgrade. You can add compatible PPAs and sources after the upgrade but do not add sources for another distro or another version of Ubuntu. Try to use default sources or snaps instead of adding sources when possible.